# Mapping and returning JSX being treated as an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object that contains other objects. This is just to keep an ID against each entry for easy referencing.

My posts data structure is as follows

```
{
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        title: "qwerty"
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        title: "asdf"
    },
}
```

I'm using lodash to loop the items as an array and return an array of JSX elements. However the return is being treated as an object.

```
postsList() {
    return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
        return (
            <a key={ post.id }>{ post.title }</a>
        );
    });
}
```

This happens no matter how I handle the transformation. I can convert the top level object to an array first then map it but I get the same results. The result is always an object. If i console log the post lists it looks as follows

```
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
0: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "a", key: "1", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
1: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "a", key: "2", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
2: {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), type: "a", key: "3", ref: null, props: {…}, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

And when I try and use the function in my component with {this.postsList()} I get the error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {rendered}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please, provide a way to replicate the problem. Nothing that you posted has an object with `rendered` key.

Answer (score 1):

The Lodash `map` method returns an array, so by returning the map, you're actually returning an array of objects, hence why you're getting the error above. Also, drop the Lodash map, it's not needed.

Take a look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/4x63fn9z/

```
const data = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        title: "qwerty"
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        title: "asdf"
    },
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {Object.values(data).map(item => (
                    <div>{item.id}</div>
                 ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

After fixing your data (you had duplicate keys), we can use `Object.values()` to give us an array of objects rather than relying upon Lodash. From there, we can loop over that array using the native `.map()` method and return the appropriate JSX.

Comment: For some reason, that works fine, but if the data is coming out of Redux, it doesn't

Comment: What does the data coming out of Redux look like exactly?

Comment: It's just like the same data, an object, and in that object another object with a key. The individual post object has id, title and some other things like publish date etc. Not sure of an easy way to extract the data as there are a fair few random keys. It's just a WordPress api result stored in a keyed object.

Comment: OK, are you getting an error or does it just not work? Have you tried console logging `Object.values(yourDataObject)` to see what the result is? It should be an array of objects.

Comment: No errors, every single method i use to convert the main object to an array works. It's only when i map that array and return the html that it for some reason becomes an array of objects. If i map the object and then return a string or false or anything else, those are set properly. It's only when i try to return html or a component.

Comment: Without seeing the full code, it's difficult to ascertain exactly what's happening I'm afraid. Could you chuck your component onto JSFiddle, etc. and just hardcode the data that you're getting from Redux so we can take a look?

Comment: I just sourced a 3'rd party WP api for data, exported the data, setup a whole JS fiddle to replicate my issues, setup the code… and it worked.

So i thought it must be my api, so i set my code to this other api, and it worked.

Swap my code back to my api… and it works

I now can't make it NOT work

literally copying the broken code out of my stack question and it works now.

I'm more confused than I've been at a code problem in a good few years at this point, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON object is incorrect. You are redefining the key `1` multiple times, the only value that is contained at the end is the last one : `{ id: 3, title: "asdf" }`

```js
const posts = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
    },
    1: {
        id: 2,
        title: "qwerty"
    },
    1: {
        id: 3,
        title: "asdf"
    },
}

console.log(posts)
```

You have 2 solutions.

The easiest solution to your problem would be to convert your object into the following array and map over it :

Working example :

```js
const posts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "qwerty"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "asdf"
    },
]

const App = props => <div>{posts.map(({ id, title }) => <a key={id}>{title}</a>)}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Another one would be to give a different key to each element and map their values :

```js
const posts = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        title: "qwerty"
    },
    3: {
        id: 3,
        title: "asdf"
    },
}

const App = props => <div>{Object.values(posts).map(({ id, title }) => <a key={id}>{title}</a>)}</div>

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Lodash does not seem to be required in any case

Comment: Lodash can call map with object as argument, not limited to array

Comment: Sorry this was me making an example of the data, they do have different IDs

Comment: Yes you can use lodash, I just said that it is not required, it is not a reason to downvote.
@ChrisMorris Alright, you can use the second solution then